# flush() and isEmpty() methods for a ring buffer without using .size() in Java

Tags: java, pointers, queue, circular-buffer

I am trying to implement a Ring (circular queue) of Chars in Java and I'm having a difficult time thinking through how to detect if the buffer isEmpty without using the .size() method on the array.

Because if the Ring Buffer is full `read pointer == write pointer` but also if the Ring Buffer is empty, `read pointer == write pointer` so I'm not sure how to check for isEmpty() correctly. I know that I can do it with .size() but I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to implement it without.

I know that I will need to waste a space at the end of the array but I'm not sure how to check it. Would the check be as simple as `if (head != (tail - 1))`?

Also, I am trying to write the `flush()` method and I think I can do so with a for each loop looking like this:

```
for(char c : items){
            c = (Character) null;
        }
```

But eclipse yells at me for null pointer access requiring auto boxing and unboxing.

Any help would be very much appreciated. The full class is below for reference:

```
public class RingBuffer {
    private char[] items;
    private int front;
    private int rear; 
    private int last;

    public RingBuffer(int capacity){
        items = new char[capacity +1];
        front = 0;
        rear = 0;
        last = capacity;

    }

    public void flush(){
        for(char c : items){
            c = (Character) null;
        }       
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why without `size()`?

Comment: What do you think `c = (Character) null;` does?

Comment: Sets that space in the array equal to null. But a quick google search yielded the default value for chars is '\u0000' so should I set it equal to that?

Comment: Yes, a primitive cannot have a `null` value. Only reference type variables can store `null`. What do you want your `flush` method to do? Simply reset the buffer? Why not just initialize a new `char[]`. Also, `c` is a brand new variable. It has no relation to the element in the array.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll do that. I can't just initialize a new array because of the .size() restriction.

Comment: I don't see how the two are related. You have the `.length` of the previous array. Just use it to create the new one.

Comment: I still didn't get the note about not using `size()`. Why is that? And what do you mean with _"size() method on the array"_? There is no _size()_ method on the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read more about **Full/Empty Buffer Distinction** on Wikipedia
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer#Full_.2F_Empty_Buffer_Distinction

There are multiple workarounds described. I would point out the one you mentioned and maybe the easiest one to understand.

**Always keep one slot open**

The buffer will never be full to the last item, but there will be always one slot empty. That means you can distinguish full from empty like this:

```java
public boolean isEmpty() {
     return head == tail;
}

public boolean isFull() {
     // don't forget about the modulo here
     return head == ((tail - 1) % capacity);
}
```

When flushing (I would name it rather `clear()`) you don't have to overwrite the data in array or allocate a new one. You can just set pointers to the beginning of the array.

```java
public void clear() {
     head = 0;
     tail = 0;
}
```

And that means the buffer will be considered empty. No matter what data are really written in memory they will be ignored and then overwritten.

---

If you liked this answer please mark it as accepted. Thank you.